# Connect Mac Excel 2016 to local MAMP SQL database

Tags: excel, odbc, mamp

As per the title I'm trying to connect to local MAMP database. This should be possible as Excel Mac 2016 includes Simba ODBC driver. However when I try and set up a connection via the dialog box shown, I always get an error shown below.
I've use the standard MAMP settings for the sql server as shown in first image.
Any help would be much appreciated as is hard to make this work.
Thanks

[MAMP settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQOf3.jpg)

[Excel Dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M1iw.jpg)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUWEk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I've finally got this connecting.

Info which solved the answer found at 
https://github.com/openlink/iODBC/issues/29

Basically excel 365 is sandboxed and so even if you create a DSN that tests ok in iODBC, it just continues to crash excel if you try to connect to it. Also I'm guessing sandboxing explains why excel is not able to see User DSNs created with iODBC, and can only see system ones.

So for others trying to connect Excel to MySQL, I needed to download iODBC to set up DSNs, and then download the iODBC connector for the ODBC drivers. 
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

I then moved the driver libraries from /usr/local/mysql.....  to /Library/ODBC/mysql...

I created a system DSN (as excel seems only to see the system ones) with keys
server    127.0.0.1
port      3306
username  root
password  *
[These details came from the MAMP page]

And then I was able to connect!